Adding additional header key-value to RabbitMQ Shovel
RabbitMQ 3.7.4
I want to use a shovel to move data from one queue to another queue that is a different version of our application and requires an additional header (static value) on the message.
According to the STATIC Shovel help, you can add headers to a static shovel, however, I cannot find any info on how to actually add the header in the configuration.
We prefer to use a DYNAMIC shovel but the help does not indicate that you can add properties or headers on dynamic shovels. Can this be done? Any examples that you can point to?
Failing this, I'll have to write my own shovel App to do this simple thing.
